# Bootstrap carousel not working properly with sinatra app

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, sinatra

Here's a link https://github.com/cheezedigital/itempiece5.git to the repo, the carousel isn't working when clicking for the next slide. I'm not sure if I'm missing some js, or proper jquery information. Any help is appreciated, really.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[There's no jquery or bootstrap js being loaded](https://github.com/cheezedigital/itempiece5/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=jquery).

Add to either `index.erb` or `layout.erb`:

```
<script src="/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

and this to the end of the HEAD section:

```
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

I'd also recommend [using a CDN for it](http://encosia.com/3-reasons-why-you-should-let-google-host-jquery-for-you/) (you could use the [Rack Jquery gem](https://github.com/yb66/rack-jquery#usage) I wrote), and using the minified version too (or naming the js file to reflect it's minified;)